# Notice: A session had already been started, I can't end my Session

Tags: php, session, internet-explorer-11

First I thought this is just an IE problem. But now I enable error codes and there this is displaying this:

Notice: A session had already been started - ignoring session_start() in /var/www/html/login.php on line 7

Line 7 is the session start command.

I have three files. **index.php, auth.php** and **login.php** which contains all the login process:

**index.php**

```
<?php

echo "<a href=\"/login.php\">Log in</a>";

?>
```

**auth.php**

```
$_user_ = 'admin';
$_password_ = 'password';

session_start();

$url_action = (empty($_REQUEST['action'])) ? 'logIn' : $_REQUEST['action'];
$auth_realm = (isset($auth_realm)) ? $auth_realm : '';

if (isset($url_action)) {
if (is_callable($url_action)) {
    call_user_func($url_action);
} else {
    echo 'Function does not exist, request terminated';
};
};

function logIn() {
global $auth_realm;

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    if (!isset($_SESSION['login'])) {
        $_SESSION['login'] = TRUE;
        header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="'.$auth_realm.'"');
        header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
        echo '<h1>Not authorized!</h1>';
        echo '<p>You must enter a valid login and password.</p>';
        echo '<a href="?action=logOut">Log in</a> | ';
        echo '<a href="../">Back to the Website</a></p>';
        exit;
    } else {
        $user = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] : '';
        $password = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']) ? $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] : '';
        $result = authenticate($user, $password);
        if ($result == 0) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $user;
        } else {
            session_unset($_SESSION['login']);
            errMes($result);
            exit;
        };
    };
};
}

function authenticate($user, $password) {
global $_user_;
global $_password_;

if (($user == $_user_)&&($password == $_password_)) { return 0; }
else { return 1; };
}

function errMes($errno) {
switch ($errno) {
    case 0:
        break;
    case 1:
        echo '<h1>Not authorized!</h1>';
        echo 'Username and password are incorrect.';
        echo '<p><a href="?action=logOut">Log in</a> | ';
        echo '<a href="../">Back to the Website</a></p>';
        break;
    default:
        echo 'Unknown error';
};
}

function logOut() {

session_destroy();
session_unset(); 

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    session_destroy($_SESSION['username']);
    foreach(array_keys($_SESSION) as $k) unset($_SESSION[$k]);
    echo "<h1>You've successfully logged out</h1>";
    echo '<a href="?action=logIn">Log In</a> | ';
    echo '<a href="../">Back to the Website</a>';
} else {
    header("Location: ?action=logIn", TRUE, 301);
};
if (isset($_SESSION['login'])) { session_unset($_SESSION['login']); };
exit;
}
```

**login.php**

```
<?php

$auth_realm = 'My Website';

require_once 'auth.php';

session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
die('Please login first <a href="login.php?action=logIn">log in</a>.');
}
echo "<p>You've logged in as {$_SESSION['username']} ";
echo '<a href="?action=logOut">Log out</a></p>'

?>
```

1. Start with index.php and click on login and enter "admin" and "password"
2. Click on Log out
3. Click on "Back to the Website"
4. Now Click on "Log in" again
5. Press cancel
6. Click on "Back to the Website"
7. Click on login.

==> Now you are logged in, without passing the username and password. This is a security lack and only works with IE 11. I tried to use several different options to delete the session, but nothing helps. Who can help me?

I also tested this with Chrome, here it works correctly and I am forced to pass the login data after point 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try logging out this way:

```
unset($_SESSION['username']);
session_destroy();
setcookie('PHPSESSID','',time()-3600,'/','',0,0); //unless you changed the PHP session cookie name
```

Comment: No, this doesn't help. Although I don't set any cookie I tried this code. The result is now I got a login window again, when I klick on log out. And the ression still remains.

Comment: Did I detect an unsolved bug for Internet Explorer or is something in my code wrong?